# Any place or forum can help to test my Windows Phone app (.xap file)?

Tags: testing, windows-phone-8

Anyone know any websites, places or forum can help me test the windows phone app i developed recently?

it is in .xap format, I wish to test the usability of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows ha its own website to test the windows phone application. The link to the website is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

It also provides a testing kit. You can visit it at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks!
But do you know places that can test on the usability and acceptance testing?